# Overloaded methods in use case diagrams

Tags: uml, overloading, use-case

Is it possible to show an overloaded method in a use case diagram? If yes how can I do that? If not what is the best way to represent an overloaded method in a use case diagram?

Comment: You should elaborate on the reason for showing classes on a UC diagram.

Answer (score 0):

full UML use case diagram specification can be found [at OMG](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF/).

The UML 2.5 doesn't specify a "derive" for use cases, but for classes, as far as I see for the first moment. But intuitive, I'd tend to a ---- <<Derives>> ----> dependency between overloaded use case and derived use case. If it's not for academic reasons, it may improve readability of a diagram if additional remarks from other UML diagrams are **carefully** applied to other diagram types.

Comment: Overloading is done by generalizing from a superclass and replacing certain operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can show anything in a UC diagram, even classes. The annex of the UML 2.5 explicitly states this (see Note in Annex A p. 683).

However, showing overloading of class operations is only recognizable from the context of the class and its superclass, by showing both the original and the overloaded operation in the operations compartments.

This question stands: why would you show this in a UC diagram?